# Using an Ubuntu VPS as a firewall/router

Tags: vpn, vps, ubuntu-12.04, ddos

I have a dedicated server running ubuntu 12.04 hosting several websites and other applications which require client IP's to be visible, however the main dedicated server does not have DDoS protection, and we have experienced a couple of DDoS attack, so i also bought a VPS with OVH(also 12.04) as they offer 450+ Gbps DDoS protections.

I am aware i could use a reverse proxy on the OVH node to protect my server, this however would leak the IP by the server replying with a direct communication, and i know i can use IPTables NAT forwarding however means that the second server sees the OVH's ip as the only client.

My question is, is it possible for me to use this OVH node like a router with full nat to the dedicated server. IE such as a VPN tunnel where i can in theroy connect multiple servers, and set custom port forwarding rules, and the dedicated server(s) gets a NAT style IP from the OVH, and so would see all the IP's correctly but not have it's own IP visible in the same way as a router does for my computer right now.

If more information is required on this question, please just say, and i apologise for anything which is unclear.

Comment: "I am aware i could use a reverse proxy on the OVH node to protect my server, this however would leak the IP by the server replying with a direct communication" <-- umm, nope, that's not how reverse proxying works.

Comment: I thought the proxy would forward all traffic to my server, but then the server would reply directly to the client?

Comment: Think through that from a TCP perspective. The client sets up a TCP socket with the proxy, and then starts the HTTP session. How would the server reply directly? There is no pre-existing socket for it to use, and the server cannot establish a socket with the client - this is something the client needs to initiate.

Comment: So then would this not cause the same thing as iptables NAT, all clients would have the exact same IP?

Comment: That is what the `X-Forwarded-For` http header is for.

Comment: The websites are mostly handled using cloudflare, there are other applications running which are just raw TCP, so can't use that feature alas.